# Identify tenant from the url in multi-tenant asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, multi-tenant

I am creating a multi-tenant asp.net application. I want my url to follow

```
**http://www.example.com/test1/test2/**{tenantName}/{controller}/{action}
**http://www.example.com/test1/**{tenantName}/{controller}/{action}
**http://www.example.com/**{tenantName}/{controller}/{action}
```

Here the part of the url in bold is fixed (will not change)
{tenantName}=will be logical tenant instance.

I have followed [this](http://lonetechie.com/2012/09/25/multi-tenant-architecture-with-asp-net-mvc-4/) link
What will be the routing to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MultiTenantRoute", // Route name
    "test1/test2/{tenantName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults, if needed
);
```

The part without braces must match. The parts inside the braces will be transfer into route data parameters. I've added an optional parameter `id`, as you usualy find in the controllers, but you can customize it. You can also give default values to tenantName, controller or action as usual.

Remember that routes are evaluated in the order they're registered, so you should probably register this route before any other.

**EDIT after question update**

You cannot specify a catch all parameter like this: `{*segment}` at the beginning of a route. That's not possible. ASP.NET MVC wouldn't know how many segments to include in this part, and how many to be left for the rest of the parameters in the route.

So, you need to add a route for each possible case,taking into account that the first route that matches will be used. So you'd need routes starting with extra parameters like this:

```
{tenanName}...
{segment1}{tenanName}...
{segment1}/{segment2}/{tenanName}...
```

Depending on the structre of the expected urls you may need to add constraints to ensure that the route is being correctly matched. This can be done passing a fourth parameter to thw `MapRoute` method. This is an anonymous class, like the deafults parameter, but the specified value for each parameter is a constraint. These constraints, on their simplest forma, are simply strings which will be used as regular expressions (regex).

If the expected URLs are extremely variable, [then implement yout own routing class](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com.es/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html).

Comment: What if I want to have "test1/test2" also changeable?

Comment: You told it was unchangeable... If it's changeable, you can use more braces, `{segment1}/{segment2}/{tenanName}...`. If you need to, you can add a 4th parameter to `MapRoute` and specify constraints for those segments (or any other thing). If you need to do something "special" you'll have to implement your own routing class, and register it.

Comment: I've edited my answer, explaining what I've just commented more deeply

Comment: Thanks. However, the solution you have given is working when I am debugging from VS, but it is not working if I host the website under same hierarchy. I get 404 error. Any thoughts?

Comment: That makes not sense. Have you restarted the server after deploying? If that doesn't solve the problem, you could try using Glimpse in the deployment server to get some insight of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could define the route as

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "TennantRoute",
                url: "test1/test2/{tenantName}/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
            );
```

and your action must take parameter with name `tenantName` because you may want make some decision based on that ...for example

```
public ActionResult Index(string tenantName)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

example : `http://localhost:19802/test1/test2/PrerakT/Home/Index`

[image]

Please make sure you define this path above the default route for following urls to work

```
http://localhost:19802/test1/test2/PrerakT/
http://localhost:19802/test1/test2/PrerakT/Home/
http://localhost:19802/test1/test2/PrerakT/Home/index
```

**What if I want test1 and test2 to be changeable ...**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "TennantRoute",
                url: "{test1}/{test2}/{tenantName}/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

and

```
public ActionResult Index(string tenantName, string test1, string test2)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

as per your update on the question

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "TennantRoute1",
                url: "test1/test2/{tenantName}/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "TennantRoute2",
                url: "test1/{tenantName}/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "TennantRoute3",
                url: "{tenantName}/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: What if I want to have "test1/test2" also changeable?

Comment: I have updated the question. Here by test1/ test2, I meant any level of virtual folder

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I meant to say that the level of virtual directory can be any thing. I will not aware of that beforehand.

Comment: you mean to say ..it could be test1/test2 or could be test1/test2/test3/test4 or anything. But why would that be ..any example that you quote help me understand the use case. Thanks.

Comment: The application will be given in the form of executable. The user can decide whatever name/ level of directories to install the application. Hope this helps

Comment: as @JotaBe noted this variable segments is not possible but you could provide a route as "{variablesegment}/{tenantName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}" and use a regex constraint which could verify for the paterrn to match "x/y/z".

Comment: Thanks. However, the solution you have given is working when I am debugging from VS, but it is not working if I host the website under same hierarchy. I get 404 error. Any thoughts?

Comment: I cannot see 404 when I hosted this locally on IIS.pls paste your route config.